# Wierd characters at the end of any email: PHP MAIL

Tags: php, email

Well I am using the PHP MAIL function and for some reason every email it sends has a weird;

```
&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;
```

This is at the end of any email as I said, I am not quite sure why this is happening.

```
        $from = 'From: support@phycraft.co.uk';
        $to = $user_email; // Send email to our user  
        $subject = 'PhyCraft Support Ticket :: Closed :: ' . $t_subject; // Give the email a subject
        $message = ' 

Hello '. $username.'.

Your support ticket '.$t_subject.' has been closed due to being inactive for 48 hours. 

If you still need help with the ticket please reopen the ticket by replying to it.

~PhyCraft 

';

        $headers = 'From:support@phycraft.co.uk' . "\r\n"; // Set from headers 
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $from); // Send our email
```

I can't see what in the code woud make that appear to be honest.

Comment: I don't have a precise solution for you, but have you tried PHPMailer? I was using `mail()` before and I ran in a lot of problem. I switched to PHPMailer 2 years ago and it is really easy to use

Comment: I'm trying to keep the code as compacts as needed so if I can get the `mail()` to work then it would be better~

Comment: If you call `mail($to, $subject, '', $from);`, do you still get the weird characters?

Comment: Those are HTML entity codes for null bytes. I've never seen that in my use of mail(). Sounds like there's garbage in `$message`.

Comment: dusan and moskito-x tried those but still appear.

Comment: Have you tried sending a mail() with a simpler $message to help narrow down the problem?  A lot of times whitespace can cause problems, as can symbols like ~.   You could also try $message = html_entity_decode($message); but this may just hide the problem.

Comment: I tried using just a blank message but they still appear. `html_entity_decode` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Most issues with php's mail() function are problems with the MTA and not with PHP itself. I've never heard of this before making it even more likely it's a MTA issue.

You've not provided any useful information beyond the PHP code. What OS is this on (mail() on MSWindows is very different from everyhere else). Do you control the server? What MTA is configured? Have you tried sending an email from the command line?

The extra stuff at the end looks like HTML - is this byte for byte what's in the email or what you see in your mail client?

BTW it's not a good idea to explicitly put "\r\n" at the *end* of your headers - but you seem to have forgotten to add them as a parameter. Also, your missing a space between "From:" and the email address.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the server is running Linux, I do not own it, it is hosted with freehostia.

Comment: That doesn't really address the questions I asked.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite get what MTA is, and I do not get access to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it with following $headers ( only \n ).

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset = \"ISO-8859-1\";\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
$headers .= "From: support@phycraft.co.uk\n"; 
$headers .= "\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

and 2. try it without

```
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
```

Comment: Still seems to be there :s

Comment: @Phyore : also with an empty $message ?